# Spinner retornando Nulo

Tags: java, android

> Meu spinner está retornando nulo,provavelmente na hora de passar pra string tem algo errado e está com um erro nestas linhas :

```
com.example.thiago.myapplication.Activity_addinf.onCreate(Activity_addinf.java: 128)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: setOnItemClickListener cannot be used with a spinner.
```

> Meu código :

```
   public class Activity_addinf extends AppCompatActivity implements IHttpConnection, AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {


   catliv = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.catergorialiv);

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("Romance");
    list.add("Direito");
    list.add("Didatico");
    list.add("Informática");
    list.add("Ficção Cientifíca");
    list.add("Infantil");
    list.add("Drama");
    list.add("Contos");

    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);

    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    catliv.setAdapter(dataAdapter);





   btnadd1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

           // mCatliv = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();



            if (mCatliv.equals("Romance")) {
                postCatLivro("http://192.168.1.207/api/v2/bookdemo/_table/cad_categorias?fields=id_cat&filter=tx_cat%3Dromance", 2);
            }
            else if (mCatliv.equals("Direito")) {
                postCatLivro("http://192.168.1.207/api/v2/bookdemo/_table/cad_categorias?fields=id_cat&filter=tx_cat%3DDireito", 3);
            }
            else if (mCatliv.equals("Didatico")) {
                postCatLivro("http://192.168.1.207/api/v2/bookdemo/_table/cad_categorias?fields=id_cat&filter=tx_cat%3DDidatico", 4);
            }
            else if (mCatliv.equals("Informática")) {
                postCatLivro("http://192.168.1.207/api/v2/bookdemo/_table/cad_categorias?fields=id_cat&filter=tx_cat%3DInform%C3%A1tica", 5);
            }
            else if (mCatliv.equals("Ficção Cientifíca")) {
                postCatLivro("http://192.168.1.207/api/v2/bookdemo/_table/cad_categorias?fields=id_cat&filter=tx_cat%3DFic%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20Cientif%C3%ADca", 6);
            }
            else if (mCatliv.equals("Infantil")) {
                postCatLivro("http://192.168.1.207/api/v2/bookdemo/_table/cad_categorias?fields=id_cat&filter=tx_cat%3DInfantil", 7);
            }
            else if (mCatliv.equals("Drama")) {
                postCatLivro("http://192.168.1.207/api/v2/bookdemo/_table/cad_categorias?fields=id_cat&filter=tx_cat%3DDrama", 8);
            }
            else if (mCatliv.equals("Contos")) {
                postCatLivro("http://192.168.1.207/api/v2/bookdemo/_table/cad_categorias?fields=id_cat&filter=tx_cat%3DContos", 9);
            }


            else {
                return;
            }



  @Override
 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

}

@Override
  public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

O erro já diz tudo. Você está tentando setar um setOnItemClickListener no Spinner em algum lugar do código, mas o Spinner não implementa esta interface. Conforme a documentação, você tem que setar o setOnItemSelectedListener